# d3js roll up a nested JSON array and sum up a total value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js

I have this JSON

```
[{
    "month": "september",
    "detail": [{
        "date": "01-09",
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "date": "02-09",
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "date": "03-09",
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "date": "04-09",
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "date": "05-09",
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "date": "06-09",
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "date": "07-09",
        "value": 0
    }]
},

{
    "month": "october",
    "detail": [{
        "date": "01-10",
        "value": 10
    }, {
        "date": "02-10",
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "date": "03-10",
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "date": "04-10",
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "date": "05-10",
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "date": "07-10",
        "value": 10
    }]
}
```

I want to roll up the all the "value" in the object "detail" for each specific month using d3nest. If you count all the values for each specific months it would result in: september-value: 30 & october-value: 40.

I've tried nesting it but I can't get it right to sum up the values for each month. see my code.

```
d3.json('runningdata.json', function (error, data) {
console.log(data);

var Total = d3.nest()
.key(function(d) { return d.month; })
.rollup(function(value) { return d3.sum(value, function(v) { return v.detail.value; }); })

.entries(data);
console.log(JSON.stringify(Total));
});
```

All of this above would result in:

```
[{"key":"september","values":0},{"key":"october","values":0}]
```

You can notice the "key" are working right, they have the month as value. but the "Values" field result in 0. what i am trying to achieve needs to be:

```
[{"key":"september","values":30},{"key":"october","values":40}]
```

But when i try this:

```
.rollup(function(value) { return d3.sum(value, function(v) { return v.detail[0].value; }); })
```

instead of:

```
.rollup(function(value) { return d3.sum(value, function(v) { return v.detail.value; }); })
```

it shows me the values of the first object in the arrays.

```
[{"key":"september","values":5},{"key":"october","values":10}]
```

What am i doing wrong? I have been reading about d3 nesting.
Any help is welcome.

Note:
Im trying achieve this to make a graph which presents the total of each months and when you click on the specific month it will view the details of its month in days.

Comment: You can just use a basic `.reduce()` function. I'll post a solution

Comment: See my updated solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use basic javascript `.reduce()` function to do the trick. This will roll up your array of object structure into a single object with the months as the property name and the sum of the values as the value. The advantage to doing it this way is that if you want to get, say, the total for the month of September, you can simply say `combined.september`, rather than having to iterate through an array, searching for the object with the `key` property equal to "september" and then extracting the value. However, if you need to keep your original structure, see the slightly modified version at the bottom of my answer.

```js
var data = [{
    "month": "september",
    "detail": [{
        "date": "01-09",
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "date": "02-09",
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "date": "03-09",
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "date": "04-09",
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "date": "05-09",
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "date": "06-09",
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "date": "07-09",
        "value": 0
    }]
},

{
    "month": "october",
    "detail": [{
        "date": "01-10",
        "value": 10
    }, {
        "date": "02-10",
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "date": "03-10",
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "date": "04-10",
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "date": "05-10",
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "date": "07-10",
        "value": 10
    }]
}];

var combined = data.reduce(function (total, current){
  total[current.month] = current.detail.reduce(function(tot, curr) {
    return tot + curr.value;
  }, 0);
  return total;
}, {});

console.log(combined);
```

#### Edit -- if you need to keep your original {"key": "..", "values", ".."} structure

You can use `.map()` rather than `.reduce()` like so:

```
var combined = data.map(function (elem){
  var total = elem.detail.reduce(function(total, current) {
    return total + current.value;
  }, 0);
  return {key: elem.month, values: total};
});

console.log(combined); 

// output:
// [ { key: 'september', value: 30 },
//   { key: 'october', value: 40 } ]
```

Comment: I don't know if your `{"key": "september", "values": 30"}` structure is required or not, but this would certainly be the most efficient way to do it, so that when you go to look up the values of a month, it is a simple property name lookup on a single object, rather than having to iterate through an array of objects and check the value of the `"key"` property

Comment: thank you this also worked perfect and i get your solution about not interating over the array anymore but instead of that use object.property.

Comment: @Downvoter, care to comment as to why this answer is not useful?

Answer (score 2):

You have to update your d3.sum function like so:

```
d3.sum(value[0].detail, function(v) {
   return v.value;
});
```

So your whole code would be:

```
var Total = d3.nest()
.key(function(d) {
    return d.month;
})
.rollup(function(value) {
    return d3.sum(value[0].detail, function(v) {
        return v.value;
    });
})
.entries(data);
```

Comment: could you explain me why value[0].detail; worked and detail[0]; value didnt work?

Comment: Because value is an array and not an object. It is an array of object containing detail as an array again. Hence we pass in value[0].detail to d3.sum method

Comment: so in this case were using the function d3.sum, then were defining the array which is value[0] in the array object "detail". after that were looking for the value which is defined as "v.value;"